# How do I do a simple Gaussian distribution algorithm to distribute points on a plane?

Tags: java, javascript, c++, algorithm, actionscript-3

What I seek is to turn a grid into a somewhat "random" plane of tiles.

I tried just multiplying Math.random() individually with the width and height of the plane (in this case its 800 / 600). The circles you see there are points that intersect each other and have been removed from the scene.

As you can see, it looks very far from an "evenly distributed" field of points. There are large holes and just as bad, clusters of points can be seen.

What I am looking for is a way to distribute these points better to have a minimum amount of clusters and holes. Ideally, to have a value that is the minimum distance between any two points, while having the maximum number of points that can fit in the area. I am fine with approximations of all kinds, I just don't want to attempt to do a greedy distribution.

Whatever ecma solution you give its fine, I can convert it to Actionscript.

[image]

I have found a visual example. The left side is what I got and the right is what I aim for.
[image]

Comment: thanks for just downvotting without a reason or suggestion -.-

Comment: Possibly it's due to language-tag spam?

Comment: Why not place them on a grid (distance=close to minimum) and modify each position with a small randomized dx,dy?

Comment: Because two neighbors can drift closer to each other and then there is countless testing and repositioning for the minimum distance to be satisfied. And it still looks grid-like.

Comment: Read the sampling section here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/

Comment: Where does "Gaussian" come into the picture? You mention it in the title, but it doesn't look like you do it, or want it. Did you mean "uniform distribution"?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb please convert it into an answer. Its what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is a non-trivial problem, and there are many different approaches.

One that I have liked, since it is fast and produces decent results, is the quasi-random number generator from this article: "[The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Quasirandom Sequences](http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/)"

Other approaches are generally iterative, where the more iterations you do, the better results. You could look up "Mitchell's Best Candidate", for one. Another is "Poisson Disc Sampling".

There are innumerable variations on the different algorithms depending on what you want — some applications demand certain frequencies of noise, for instance. But if you just want something that "looks okay", I think the quasirandom one is a good starting point.

Another cheap and easy one is a "jittered grid", where you evenly space the points on your plane, then randomly adjust each one a small amount.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Loyds algorithm, i.e. centroidal weighted voronoi diagrams. Compute the vd and then the center of gravity of each cell. Replace the old points and rinse and repeat: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/.